# Clustering accuracy check with Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, confusion-matrix

I have an accident location dataset. I have applied several clustering algorithms on this dataset using the column latitude and longitude. Now I would like to measure the accuracy of different clustering algorithms separately to compare between them.

I want to apply the confusion matrix described in this [article](https://smorbieu.gitlab.io/accuracy-from-classification-to-clustering-evaluation/).

But I am not able to understand what I should consider as a label? I have made my clusters using only two columns latitude and longitude. Can anyone guide me, please? I have the code but it's not clear to me. I mean what is the label or class label in my case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

In a confusion matrix you provide two sets of labels for each entry. One of these labels is the cluster assignment generated by the clustering you did. The second label can be the ground truth, which allows you to determine accuracy/precision.

Your case sounds like there is no ground truth, so you can't compare for accuracy. You CAN use the result of one of the different algorithms you used as the second set of labels, to compare the result between these two clusterings.

Comment: But in my case one algorithm gives 10 clusters and another one gives 13clusters. As far i know confusion matrix is a n*n matrix.

Comment: No, confusion matrix does not have to be square, it's just easier to interpret when it is square.